# stitch mongoClient auth AnonymousCredential dont continue inside the continueWith

Tags: mongodb, stitch

i am logging in to make a search on mongodb stitch client. 
but after the AnonymousCredential authentication it does nothing.

kt code:

```
    val mongoClient = client!!.getServiceClient(RemoteMongoClient.factory, "mongodb-atlas")
    client!!.auth
    .loginWithCredential(AnonymousCredential())
    .continueWith{ task -> { ...some code... } }
```

but it never gets to the "some code" part. 
and i dont know why cause in stitch UI logs i get OK status:

```
{
  "arguments": [
    {
      "database": "test",
      "collection": "users",
      "query": {
        "id": ""
      },
      "limit": {
        "$numberInt": "1"
      },
      "project": null,
      "sort": null
    }
  ],
  "name": "find",
  "service": "mongodb-atlas"
}
Function Call Location: US-VA
Compute Used: 624980924 bytes•ms
Remote IP Address: 201.124.215.137
SDK: android v0.0
Platform Version: 8.1.0
Rule Performance Metrics:
{
  "test.users": {
    "roles": {
      "default": {
        "matching_documents": 1,
        "evaluated_fields": 0,
        "discarded_fields": 0
      }
    },
    "no_matching_role": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: When you login to Stitch, the first page you see is the Welcome to Stitch page that has a Getting Started guide beneath it.  Have you followed the steps to turn on anonymous authentication and initialize your collection?  Does the sample code in the "Execute a Test Request" section on that page work for you?

Comment: yes. and it worked for a while , but today it didnt, and i dont know where to start check it.

Comment: commencted all my code and got back to the basics of the getting started example and it got into the inner section. ill continue from there. thnx

Comment: glad you were able to make some progress!